# Where are my binaries after an MSBuild task?

Tags: azure-pipelines, msbuild-task

In my VSTS build definition, I have an MSBuild of which I want to access the artifacts.
Although the task's log states it built everything and copied it to bin\debug* when the build is done there is no link to Artifacts.

> 2017-07-27T14:27:49.1024373Z   Copying file from
>   "obj\Debug\myfile.pdb" to
>   "bin\Debug\myfile.pdb".

I tried following up with a Publish Artifact task that would copy from `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` or from `$(Build.BinariesDirectory)` but to no avail.
I tried adding a Copy Files task with the same source folders and `**/$(BuildConfiguration)/**/?(*.*)` as contents, but 0 files were found.

Where are my MSBuild's output files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this screenshot to configure Copy Files task, then specify $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) for Publish Artifact task (Path to publish)

[image]